# Spring Security: authorize all request, except coming from trusted subnet

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have this lines in my config class:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

Now I want all requests from trusted subnet to bypass Spring Security without authorization.

So, I fixed my configuration:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**").hasIpAddress(127.0.0.1/24)
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

Ok, machine-to-machine communication inside private subnet now works good.
Unfortunately, authorized clients from web browser have 401 error every single time.

Is there a way to write `OR` condition?

Like this: `client has ip #.#.#.# OR should be authorized`

Comment: Just write an expression instead of using the methods. Use `access` instead. Write something like `anyRequest().access("hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1/24') or isAuthenticated()")`

Comment: Yes, I missed that option. It really works, thank you. Could you please write this as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The methods like `hasIpAddress` and `authenticated` or `hasRole` are there for simple access rules. Underneath they all call the `access` method to add an expression. You can also use this yourself to write more complex security expressions.

```
http.authorizeRequests()        
    .anyRequest().access("hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1/24') or isAuthenticated()");
```

There is a small mention of [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#authorize-requests) in the Spring Security reference guide.